# Alternate to recursively Running Spark-submit jobs

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

Below is the scenario I would need suggestions on,

Scenario:

Data ingestion is done through Nifi into Hive tables.

Spark program would have to perform ETL operations and complex joins on the data in Hive.

Since the data ingested from Nifi is continuous streaming, I would like the Spark jobs to run every 1 or 2 mins on the ingested data.

Which is the best option to use?

Trigger spark-submit jobs every 1 min using a scheduler?
How do we reduce the over head and time lag in submitting the job recursively to the spark cluster? Is there a better way to run a single program recursively?

Run a spark streaming job?
Can spark-streaming job get triggered automatically every 1 min and process the data from hive? [Can Spark-Streaming be triggered only time based?]

Is there any other efficient mechanism to handle such scenario?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you need something that runs every minute you better use spark-streaming and not batch.
2. You may want to get the data directly from kafka and not from hive table, since it is faster.

As for your questions what is better batch / stream. You can think of spark streaming as micro batch process that runs every "batch interval".

Read this : https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html

Comment: We had two problems to use Kafka into Spark Streaming. 1) Kafka Oracle Connector had the below issue - https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-jdbc/issues/101                                                 2) Performing complex joins on multiple streams of data (multiple topics of data from multiple tables) was very difficult in streaming.                                         Is there a way to get around these problems?